# Bad characters when printing text from utf8_unicode_ci Mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8

I insert/update text to utf8_unicode_ci encoded table with `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`

It appears like "ş,ğ,ü" in the mysql table. But when i print it with PHP,

it appears like "� ??" on the page.

I tried to add

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

but didn't work.

How can i show unicode chars correctly on the page ?

Thanks

Comment: Try calling `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` in your PHP code. Also could you check if your browser is indeed processing the document as UTF-8? In Chrome you check this by clicking the Wrench Icon->Tools->Encoding

Comment: I checked browser's encoding it is UTF-8 and i called PHP header but didnt work :(

Comment: Did you also `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` before fetching the data from MySQL, i.e. `SELECT * FROM ...`?

Comment: @Basti Yes, i added it just after mysql connection

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be using :

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

instead of

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'")
```

and I would suggesting setting headers in PHP too

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 Settings for PHP:

```
ini_set("mbstring.language", "Neutral");
ini_set("mbstring.internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
ini_set("mbstring.encoding_translation", "On");
ini_set("mbstring.http_input", "auto");
ini_set("mbstring.http_output", "UTF-8");
ini_set("mbstring.detect_order", "auto");
ini_set("mbstring.substitute_character", "none");
ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");
ini_set("mbstring.func_overload", 7);

setlocale(LC_TIME, "en_US.UTF-8");
```