# replacing characters with UTF-8 after using mysql_set_charset('utf8') function

Tags: php, utf-8

I converted all mysql tables to utf-8_unicode and started using `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` function.

But after this, some characters like Ş, Ö started looking like  Ã– , Åž

How can i replace this kinda letters in mysql with UTF-8 format ?

shortly, can i find a list of all these kinda characters to replace ?

EDIT:
He is explaining about this issue in this article actually but i cannot understand it properly acutally lol

http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2006/01/turning_mysql_data_in_latin1_t.html

Answer (score 10):

you dont need to do that. just use this code after database connect.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
```

and use utf-8 charset in all of your pages.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: check this page, someone suggested me to use mysql_set_charset instead of set names as i was using it before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703536/bad-characters-when-printing-text-from-utf8-unicode-ci-mysql-table

Comment: ı am using this and its perfectly works fine. and ı am using both, set names and set charset like he says.

Comment: actually problem is not about printed text, problem is about the stored text in mysql. i gotta replace them.

Comment: ı cant understand. now ı am using these codes and when ı insert something to database it store as "ö ç ğ ı" and printing it like storing. you dont need to replace anything. --->>>

ahmet bey bu dediğim şekilde yaparsanız hiçbir sorun yaşamayacaksınız. şuan veritabanına bir şey eklediğimde nasılsa öyle kaydediyor, yazdırdığımda da olduğu gibi yazdırıyor sorun yok yani.

Comment: demek istediğim şu, tablolar eskiden latindeyken ö ç ğ diye kaydetmiyordu, utf-8 e geçince normal olarak öyle kaydetmeye başladı ama eskiden gelen kötü karakterler var şu an ve onları düzeltmem gerekiyor.

Comment: This answer is dangerous.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php warns that if you don't call mysql_set_charset(), mysql_real_escape_string() will not escape all characters correctly which may allow SQL injection attacks.  There's a reason the mysql_set_charset() doc page warns you not to call "SET NAMES 'utf8'" and similar directly.

Answer (score 4):

This PHP script allows you to convert your existing database and tables to UTF-8:

```
<?php

  // Database connection details 
  $db_srv = 'localhost';
  $db_usr = 'user'; 
  $db_pwd = 'password'; 
  $db_name = 'database name';

  // New charset information, update accordingly if not UTF8
  $char_set = 'utf8';
  $char_collation = 'utf8_general_ci';

  header('Content-type: text/plain'); 

  // extablish the connection
  $connection = mysql_connect($db_srv,$db_usr,$db_pwd) or die(mysql_error()); 

  // select the databse
  $db = mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error()); 

  // get existent tables
  $sql = 'SHOW TABLES';
  $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

  // for each table found
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res))
  {   
    // change the table charset
    $table = mysql_real_escape_string($row[0]); 

    $sql = " ALTER TABLE ".$table." 
             DEFAULT CHARACTER SET ".$char_set." 
             COLLATE ".$char_collation; 

    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    echo 'The '.$table.' table was updated successfully to: '.$char_set."\n";
  }

  // Update the Collation of the database itself
  $sql = "ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET ".$char_set.";";
  mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

  echo 'The '.$db_name.' database collation';
  echo ' has been updated successfully to: '.$char_set."\n";

  // close the connection to the database
  mysql_close($connection);

?>
```

Save it on a file, lets say `db_charset.php`, upload it to the root of your website and execute it from the browser:

**e.g.,**

```
http://www.yoursite.com/db_charset.php
```

---

Other considerations are necessary to have everything working properly after the conversion:

- The PHP files being used should be encoded with UTF-8
- The PHP headers and HTML headers should also be set to UTF-8