# MySQL, Python - Latin-1/UTF8 Encoding

Tags: php, python, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have read around setting MySQL tables/DB to `UTF8_general_ci` charset from the default `latin-1` where I was having an error inserting particular unicode strings into the MySQL table from my Python script. I deleted the entire DB, and recreated it with:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

And I then created my tables within this schema appended with:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I have a Python script feeding into the table(s) with the MySQLdb driver, I have specified the charset at the beginning of the script with:

```
connectToDb = mdb.connect(host="localhost",
                          user="me",
                          passwd="me",
                          db="me",
                          charset="utf8",
                          use_unicode=True)
```

Records feed into the DB tables without encoding error. My problem is that I have a DB driven intranet site (using PHP script to make the table entry) running from these records and a number of the records in the `<td>`'s are sohwing as containing glyphs when I use Chrome to the web page.

I have specified my PHP connection in the HTML of the page as:

`$connect = mysql_connect("localhost",$usrname,$password,"charset='utf8'");`

In particular the GB "£" symbol is causing the offence (when I check PHPmyadmin I can see that it is a "£" symbol in the GUI).

I do not know what the cause is, can you help? Thanks.

EDIT: The HTML page also has the following declared:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Answer (score 1):

1.Remove "charset='utf8'" from mysql_connect - it is incorrect.

2.Try using [mysql_set_charset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) after connecting

```
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', $user, $password);
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connect);
```

PS

mysql_* functions are deprecated, don't use them. Consider switching to PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: Thanks or the pointer about mysql_* functions. I've found a good resource here: http://codular.com/php-mysqli. I was just about to do what you have suggested but came across the following page which works great: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864711/replacing-characters-with-utf-8-after-using-mysql-set-charsetutf8-function

Comment: @I_lost_my_last_account Did you try my approach? Using mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); directly is not recommended, look at the note here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Answer (score 0):

From @guybennet: [replacing characters with UTF-8 after using mysql_set_charset('utf8') function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864711/replacing-characters-with-utf-8-after-using-mysql-set-charsetutf8-function)

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
and use utf-8 charset in all of your pages.
```

and the use of:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```