# Multibyte Handling in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

I have a situation where I am getting some emails which contain multi-byte sequences such as =E2=80=90. I parse these emails and stick them into a MySQL database.

Initially I noticed the sequence noted above and tried using quoted_printable_decode. That didn't work as it just stuck characters like the Euro symbol (rather than the apostrophe I was expecting). If I use UTF_encode it didn't work. I thought some sequence of utf8_encode and iconv(), but honestly I'm just flailing around. I haven't done any foreign character processing before so I was hoping someone could point me to the solution.

I am using PHP 5.6 and MySQL 5.6. The MySQL table is UTF-8 enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try `iconv` like:

```
echo iconv("ISO-8859-2", "UTF-8", quoted_printable_decode("=E1=E2"));
```

Additionally you should [set up the HTML and MySQL encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9703640/2290926):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
// After MySQL connect:
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

I hope this helps!